# I need to use a newly merged document to create a pdf, add it to a specific gdrive folder, note the pdf url on GSheet, then delete merged GDoc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm seeing a lot of other posts about "mail merge" but none of them go through all the steps I'm trying to achieve..

1. Get all row data from a Gsheet and merge it to a copied Gdoc (from a template)
2. Use the newly merged Gdoc to generate a copy as a PDf
3. Take pdf and send it as an attachment within an email
4. Save the pdf to Gdrive under a specific folder (folder names by date)
5. Delete the Gdoc that the PDF was generated from.

I'm trying to get through all these steps within one script at the moment. I assume there are better ways involving different triggers but I've put this together asap because it needed to be implemented at work. So now I'm trying to go back and improve the code (since I wasn't able to achieve all the desired steps above).

As of now, I was able to generate the merged doc and send it as a PDF within an email. I haven't been able to save the PDF copy of the newly created Gdoc within Gdrive, I'm only saving the Gdoc version (which I don't want, I just want to save the PDF).

Also, I'm only saving everything to one folder at the moment. Ideally, I'd like to loop through a parent folder, see if a folder already exists (by the same name..which is a date), then create that folder if it doesn't exist.

I've been googling and trying lots of things over the past couple days but I can't get a real good grasp on this "blob" idea with GAS and am not quite sure if I NEED to use some kind of authentication within the script in order to access the PDF that's generated (while the script is still running).

```
var rowNum = ss.getDataRange().getLastRow();
var tstamp = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, 9).getValue();
var pname = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 2, 1, 9).getValue();
var phone = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 3, 1, 9).getValue();
var email = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 4, 1, 9).getValue();
var address = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 5, 1, 9).getValue();
var city = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 6, 1, 9).getValue();
var state = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 7, 1, 9).getValue();
var zip = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 8, 1, 9).getValue();
var dob = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 9, 9, 9).getValue();
var rdate = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 10, 1, 10).getValue();
var dobf = Utilities.formatDate(dob, "GMT-7", "MM/dd/yyyy");

//Start GOOGLE DOC
var docTemplateId = "1ZtOZ6c****KF86JKHeqpeH****TcLG-3laftW2SEirHA";

//Make A Copy Of The Template To Folder Then Grab ID
var newDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplateId).makeCopy(pname, destinationFolder);  var documentId = newDoc.getId();

//Rename The Copied Template
var newName = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName("Sales Lead | " + pname);

//Open The Copied Doc
var openNewFile = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);

//Get ID of New Doc
var newId = openNewFile.getId();

//Get ID of New Doc
var body = openNewFile.getBody();

//Get URL of New Doc (used to print out download link on Gsheet upon completion)
var docURL = openNewFile.getUrl();

//Replace the tags on the Gdoc Template
body.replaceText("{{Timestamp}}", tstamp);
body.replaceText("{{Name}}", pname);
body.replaceText("{{Phone Number}}", phone);
body.replaceText("{{Email}}", email);
body.replaceText("{{Street Address}}", address);
body.replaceText("{{City}}", city);
body.replaceText("{{State}}", state);
body.replaceText("{{Zip Code}}", zip);
body.replaceText("{{Date of Birth}}", dobf);
body.replaceText("{{Date Received}}", today);

//Add Users
var addUsers = openNewFile.addEditor('example@gmail.com');
var save = openNewFile.saveAndClose();

//Generate PDF
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newId).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var pdfURL = DriveApp.getFileById(newId).getUrl();

//Create Attachment
var attach = {fileName: 'Sales Lead | ' + pname, content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

//Write "Today's" Date
var writeDate = sheet.getRange("J"+rowNum).setValue(today);

//Write Lead "Complete" And Add "Link"
var complete = sheet.getRange("K"+rowNum).setValue("ASBsw Lead Generated");

//Write URL to GSheet
var writeURL = sheet.getRange("L"+rowNum).setValue(pdfURL);

//Send Email
MailApp.sendEmail("company@mycompany.com", "Sales Lead | " + pname + " | " + today, "See Attached PDF", {
  attachments: [attach],
  name: newName
});
```

**Missing Steps**

1. Loop through GDrive Folders (within a parent) and check for a (child) folder that exists, using the 'dobf' variable from the GSheet data. If it doesn't exist, create it. If it does, move the new PDF to that folder.
2. This code is currently saving a GDoc to GDrive. Instead, I want a PDF copy of the GDoc, save it to specified folder, then delete the GDoc
3. Print out the download URL for the newly created PDF to GSheets...instead of printing the GDoc url (as I am now).

P.S. I know this isn't very "DRY" code in some instances. So more experienced coders wont like to see the repetition that's listed above. I started learning coding about 10 months ago and GAS, about a week ago. I was using an Add-on to accomplish all this before and it suddenly went BLACK last week! This produced a region-wide meltdown of our company automation, which...wasn't good (to put it lightly). I literally bought Udemy course and learned GAS over a couple days and was able to get our automations back up and running a couple days ago (there's 4 other similar merges we use). 
I do apologize to those more experienced coders that may be reading this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I have to apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. And can you post the completed script  for your situation as an answer and accept it? By this, other users can see your question as the solved question. About my answer, in order to avoid confusion, I think that my answer has to be removed. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Answer (score 0):

@Tanaike, sounds like you're way too hard on yourself. You definitely led me down the right path. That counts buddy. Here's the rest of the answer I was looking for....

```
    //Generate PDF from merged GDoc
    var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(newId);
    var pdf = doc.getBlob();
    //Declare the folder to search for within parent
    var folderSearch = parFolder.searchFolders('title contains "'+aDate+'"');
    //If child folder found
    if(folderSearch.hasNext()){
      //Grab that folder
      var folNext = folderSearch.next();
      //Add newly generated pdf
      var addPdf = folNext.createFile(pdf);
    } else {
      //If folder not found, create one
      var createFold = parFolder.createFolder(aDate);
      //Grab the newly created folder
      var folNext = parFolder.getFoldersByName(aDate).next();
      //Add newly generate pdf
      var addPdf = folNext.createFile(pdf);
    }

    //Get url to view pdf
    var pdfURL = "https://drive.google.com/open?&export=download&id=" + addPdf.getId();

    //Trash the merged GDoc
    doc.setTrashed(true);

    //Print the new pdf url to the GSheet
    var writeURL = sheet.getRange("AT"+rowNum).setValue(pdfURL);
```